# How to store multiple values into tableview NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to store multiple values into single tableview `NSMutableArray`. I want to execute single `tableview row`  with multiple `values` on multiple label like below.

```
------------------------------------------------------
 Name        age    |    height    |    weight     // Row one section
------------------------------------------------------ 
Jack          23     |      123      |      45     // Row two 
------------------------------------------------------
Nano         31     |      173      |      65      // Row three 
------------------------------------------------------
```

Above diagram is mentioning `tableview` single row with multiple custom label different type of values. Right now I am maintaining separate arrays for separate values, but I cant sort by name and age to all. So I want to store all the data into single `NSMutableArray` and listing on `tableview with sorting`.

Sorry, I haven't any sample code. Please read my problem and give some sample code. Thanks

Comment: do you wanted to display whole row data in one cell right ?

Comment: I have already showing by using different array for different column values(name,age,..). Now the problem is I can't sort by name. For example. If I sort by name then need to change relevant values aso. Its everything diferent array so i can't. Please give some code for storing all datas into single NSMutable array and how to split and append different label with sort by name.@Hello

Comment: okay. You can use array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSDictionary` objects. Like this:

```
NSDictionary *object1 = @{ @"name" : @"Jack", @"age" : @(23), @"height" : @(123), @"weight" : @(45) };
NSDictionary *object2 = @{ @"name" : @"Nano", @"age" : @(31), @"height" : @(173), @"weight" : @(65) };
NSArray *array = @[ object1, object2 ];
```

And then sort it using `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSDictionary as array item. Like that you can do:

```
NSMutableArray *arTableElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"Name"];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"age"];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"height"];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"weight"];

[arTableElements addObject:dic];

//add second element
dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"Name"];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"age"];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"height"];
[dic setValue:@"23" forKey:@"weight"];
[arTableElements addObject:dic];

...

[table reloadData];
```

And so on.
After you use these dictionaries in cellForRow method to fill the label values

PS. For header use section header not a row...

Comment: all the values I am receiving from JSON. So if I receive by string and assign the values to set values then Can I list out tableview with different cell labels? and I need to sort the values by name

Comment: How to sort the values by name? Acending and decending order. Button first click to acending then second click to change names decending relavent values (age,height,..)@Antonijo

Comment: @Antonijio..your code is working good thank you, How can I show that values different label? The different labels different text colors.

Comment: Create cell rows in interface builder, that is the easiest way, than create subclass of UITableViewCell and in that subclass create IBOutlets of labels you want to fill, than use cellForRow delegate method to fill the values. You should find some tutorial about UITableViews cause it is pretty hard to desctibe this in comments

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Person` model class instead of using multiple arrays,

The model class should have properties like name, age, height..

The model class resembles like,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *age;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *height;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *weight;


@end
```

Instead of creating arrays for a property, you should use an array of `Person` objects

```
- (NSMutableArray *)prepareModelClass
{
    NSMutableArray *personsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < namesArray.count; i++) {
        Person *personObject = [Person new];// create a person object
        personObject.name = namesArray[i]; //assign properties
        personObject.age = agesArray[i];
        personObject.weight = weightsArray[i];
        [personsArray addObject:personsArray]; //add person object to single array
    }

    return personsArray;//you should use this array as data source for table view
}
```